# Advanced sorting in datagridview with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

So i have done simple search with checkboxes like this:
[image]
Here is the code for `sort` button:

```
private void sort_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cntr_check.Checked == true && pos_check.Checked == true)
            {
                var query = from o in this.leodata.main
                            where o.country.Contains(cntr_combo.Text) && o.position.Contains(pos_combo.Text) && o.price <= price_bar.Value
                            select o;
                mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }
            else if (cntr_check.Checked == true && pos_check.Checked == false)
            {
                var query = from o in this.leodata.main
                            where o.country.Contains(cntr_combo.Text) && o.price <= price_bar.Value
                            select o;
                mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }
            else if (cntr_check.Checked == false && pos_check.Checked == true)
            {
                var query = from o in this.leodata.main
                            where o.position.Contains(pos_combo.Text) && o.price <= price_bar.Value
                            select o;
                mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                var query = from o in this.leodata.main
                            where o.price <= price_bar.Value
                            select o;
                mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }

        }
```

Now i need to make an advanced search:
[image]
i tried to make it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (spain_check.Checked == true)
            {
                var query = from o in this.leodata.main
                            where o.country.Contains(spain_check.Text)
                            select o;
                mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }
            if (france_check.Checked == true)
            {
                var query = from o in this.leodata.main
                            where o.country.Contains(france_check.Text)
                            select o;
                mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

where `spain_check` and `france_check` is my checkboxes.
I had an idea that i will check every chechboxes and if `Checked == true` then i will just add new rows from mysql. But it keeps updating my table instead of adding new rows.

how can i do it?

Comment: you need to look at the values of all your checkboxes etc and use that to gradually build up your query statement. Only once you know all the parameters can you build the final query and run it. How you've got it now it will keep making a new query for each checkbox value, and only respecting that one value. It all needs to be one single process.

Comment: The form repaint method may not be called.  The trick is to set the datasource to null to get it to repaint : mainBindingSource.DataSource = null; mainBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();